# Sass/scss 'mixin as a function' to return a string with parameters?

Tags: css, sass

I have a Mixin in LESS with parameters that returns a string. I use this mixin calculate responsive properties like margins, paddings and font-sizing between two given sizes. I need help to convert it to scss.

The LESS Mixin:

```
@minscreensize: 36; // (360px) this is a rem value (without unit)
@maxscreensize: 192; // (1920px) this is a rem value (without unit)

.screenbased-calculation(@minvalue, @maxvalue, @minscreensize, @maxscreensize, @divider: 1, @multiply: 1) {
    @result: calc((unit(@minvalue, rem) + (@maxvalue - @minvalue) * (100vw - unit(@minscreensize, rem)) / (@maxscreensize - @minscreensize)) / @divider * @multiply);
}
```

Usage:

```
// First value is margin-bottom at mobile res. (12px), second value (20px) is at desktop res.
margin-bottom: .screenbased-calculation(1.2, 2.0, @minscreensize, @maxscreensize)[@result];
```

LESS Output:

```
margin-bottom: calc((1.2rem + (2.0 - 1.2) * (100vw - 36rem)/(192 - 36))/1 * 1)
```

---

I can't figure out how to convert this LESS mixin to SCSS. A Mixin appears to only output css and a function only a number.

Tryout SCSS Function

```
@function screenbased-calculation($minvalue, $maxvalue, $minsc: $minscreensize, $maxsc: $maxscreensize, $divider: 1, $multiply: 1){
    @return calc($minvalue + ($maxvalue - $minvalue) * (100vw - $minscreensize) / ($maxscreensize - $minscreensize) / $divider * $multiply);
}
```

Usage:

```
font-size: screenbased-calculation($minvalue: 3.2, $maxvalue: 6.4);
```

SCSS Output (Just a string, without the given parameters):

```
font-size: calc($minvalue + ($maxvalue - $minvalue) * (100vw - $minscreensize) / ($maxscreensize - $minscreensize) / $divider * $multiply); }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because these variables have to be interpolated.

```
$minscreensize: 36;
$maxscreensize: 192;

@function screenbased-calculation($minvalue, $maxvalue, $minsc: $minscreensize, $maxsc: $maxscreensize, $divider: 1, $multiply: 1) {
    @return calc(#{$minvalue} + #{($maxvalue - $minvalue)} * #{(100vw - $minscreensize)} / #{($maxscreensize - $minscreensize)} / #{$divider} * #{$multiply});
}

.foo {
  font-size: screenbased-calculation($minvalue: 3.2, $maxvalue: 6.4);
  // output: calc(3.2 + 3.2 * 64vw / 156 / 1 * 1);
}
```

[Here is the documentation about `interpolation` from Sass](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_)